# Web Server not sending email

Tags: php, email, laravel

I face a serious issue that I can't send emails to my clients when I update something on my website. When someone contacts me using the website contact form it doesn't come to my email but it does store in the database. It worked fine before 10th March 2015, after this time sending email with Laravel mostly doesn't work. I have tried to configure it in different ways but haven't found a solution.

**My Mail Config: /public_html/app/config/mail.php**

```
'driver' => 'mail',
'host' =>'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 597,
'from' => array(
  'address' => 'my email address', 
  'name' => 'Awesome site'
),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'my gmail username',
'password' => '',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

and my " /public_html/app/controllers" route main codes are -

```
$validation = Validator::make($contact_info, $rules);

if ($validation->passes()) 
{

    $insert = Contact::create($contact_info);

    $data = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email_id, 'message' => $contactmessage);

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($email_id, $name)
    {
        $message->from($email_id, $name);

        $message->to('My Email', 'My Subject')->subject('New Contact from user');
    });
}
```

If anyone knows about this problem please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Any error when you try to send an email ?

Comment: Is any error showing up in the log when the email is sent?

Comment: This is not really a solution to your problem, but a suggestion that might solve your issue. I wont suggest using gmail, hotmail, you will face alot of unknown issues, because they have system checking ip location, spams filters and etc, and when you use your login information on your laravel host, that could trigger spam alert and deny your message, I have had a lot of issues, try mandrill or mailgun.org it worked for me from day one, it is free for less then 10000 email month, or other free email services around. Mandrill is best with API secret key in stead of stmp it save you a lot of time

Comment: This is a server issue not Laravel (your code looks OK). If you are on a shared host, you need to talk to your hosting company about then enabling PHP's `mail` function so that Laravel can send the email out. If they can't I'd suggest using SMTP or a service like Mandrill.